# get count from Iqueryable<T> in linq-to-sql?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, count, iqueryable

The following code doesn't seem to get the correct count.....

```
 var materials = consRepository.FindAllMaterials().AsQueryable();
 int count = materials.Count();
```

Is it the way to do it.... Here is my repository which fetches records...

```
public IQueryable<MaterialsObj> FindAllMaterials()
        {
           var materials =  from m in db.Materials
            join Mt in db.MeasurementTypes on m.MeasurementTypeId equals Mt.Id
                   where m.Is_Deleted == 0
                   select new MaterialsObj()
                   {
                       Id = Convert.ToInt64(m.Mat_id),
                       Mat_Name = m.Mat_Name,
                       Mes_Name = Mt.Name,
                   };
            return materials;

        }
```

**Edit:**

when i use this,

```
        var materials = consRepository.FindAllMaterials().AsQueryable();
        return View("Materials", materials);
```

I get 18 rows in my table... So y cant i get the count as `18` instead it gives `12`

**Ans:**

Breakpoint doesn't seem produce me the result but response.Write(count) did...

Comment: Why are you converting to `IQueryable`? `IQueryable<MaterialsObj>` has a `Count()` method already. What discrepancy are you observing between the expected and actualy counts?

Comment: How do you know the count is incorrect? What should it return as opposed to what is returned?

Comment: This cant be, re-install Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the correct count:

```
int count = consRepository.FindAllMaterials().Count();
```

How are you iterating through the model in your view?

Is it possible that you are displaying duplicate entries?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're not joining on the correct columns? The only reason I ask is that your id columns aren't consistently named in each class.  For Materials you are using `Mat_id`, but in MeasurementTypes you are using simply, `Id`.  It makes me wonder if you're trying to join a natural key value against an artificial primary key instead of the corresponding natural foreign key.

Comment: @tvanoffosson `db.Materials` has `measurementTypeId` which is a foriegn key  and its primary key table is `db.MeasurementTypes` and the primary key field is `Id`...

Comment: @Pandiya - the code looks like it should work to me so I assumed that there must be something wrong with the query.  That was the only thing that I saw that could be an issue.